# Scikit Learn OneHotEncoded Features causing error in classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, predictive-modeling, categorical-data, dataframe

I’m trying to prepare data for input to a Decision Tree and Multinomial Naïve Bayes Classifier.

This is what my data looks like (pandas dataframe):

```
Label  Feat1  Feat2  Feat3  Feat4

0        1     3       2      1
1        0     1       1      2
2        2     2       1      1
3        3     3       2      3
```

I have split the data into dataLabel and dataFeatures.
Prepared dataLabel using `dataLabel.ravel()`

I need to discretize features so the classifiers treat them as being categorical not numerical.

I’m trying to do this using `OneHotEncoder`:

```
enc = OneHotEncoder()

enc.fit(dataFeatures)
chk = enc.transform(dataFeatures)
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

mnb = MultinomialNB()

from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
scores = cross_val_score(mnb, Y, chk, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')
```

I get this error: `bad input shape (64, 16)`

This is the shape of label and input:

`dataLabel.shape = 72`
`chk.shape = 72,16`

Why won't the classifier accept the onehotencoded features?

**EDIT: Adding how I got dataFeatures**

`dataFeatures = data[['Accpred', 'Gyrpred', 'Barpred', 'altpred']]`

`Y = dataLabel.ravel()`

Comment: how did you get the dataFeatures? Did you combine all the features(Feat1, Feat2..) into a list or so? and what is Y?

Comment: @HimaVarsha I've edited the question to include that :)

Comment: What does the Y mean?

Comment: @HimaVarsha Y is dataLabel - I've also added that to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scores = cross_val_score(mnb, Y, chk, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')
```

You have your `Y` and `chk` switched. That's it. :)

The signature of [`cross_val_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score.html) is `sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score(estimator, X, y)`.

`X` is a matrix and `y` is a 1D vector with your class labels.

unlike in R, most (or all?) sklearn models do not support categorical variables. Most of the time, encoding your feature matrix `X` into what is called [one-hot encoding](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) is good enough.

Notice that, in some models, this hack is not the same as true native categorical support, and the performance of the model will be worse.

**Invert One-Hot Encoding**

Sklearn does not seem to have an easy method to invert the one-hot encoding.

It is not trivial how to do this. I found [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35898452/2680707):

```
def inverse(enc, out, shape):
    return np.array([enc.active_features_[col] for col in out.sorted_indices().indices]).reshape(shape) - enc.feature_indices_[:-1]
```

Example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
enc = OneHotEncoder()
X = np.array([[0, 0, 3], [1, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2]]))
Z = enc.fit_transform(X)
print(inverse(enc, Z, X.shape))
# [[0 0 3]
#  [1 1 0]
#  [0 2 1]
#  [1 0 2]]
print(X)
# [[0 0 3]
#  [1 1 0]
#  [0 2 1]
#  [1 0 2]]
```

Notice:

- This only works when `HotOneEncoding(sparse=True)` (default) because it uses scipy sparse matrix methods (this could be changed by making the code only use numpy methods), but this is probably what you want since working with a dense matrix will kill your memory anyhow
- I think this will only work if your variables are within the range [0,something] because you lose that information in the transformation (no work-around for this other than you using something like [DictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html) which offers you more control over the transformation.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, I have been stuck on this for longer than I care to admit :) Is there any way to map encoded labels back to original labels(integers) after prediction?

Comment: @gbhrea I am a little confused. But I edited my answer. Please see if it helps...

Comment: Ricardo - sorry I confused myself there - what I meant to say was is there any way to map encoded features back to their original labels?

Comment: @gbhrea Ah okay, see my updated answer then :)